# mvn appengine:update from Bamboo requires credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, bamboo

I have a maven project that updates appspot with my war, but when the build is executed by [Atlassian Cloud Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/Cloud/Bamboo+Cloud) the OAuth authentication prompts for access tokens.

```
14-May-2015 00:17:18    [INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
14-May-2015 00:17:18    [INFO] Updating Google App Engine Application
14-May-2015 00:17:18    [INFO] Running -V 1.9.20 --oauth2 update /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/[project path]-1-SNAPSHOT
14-May-2015 00:17:21    Please open the following URL in your browser:
14-May-2015 00:17:21      https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

Opening the url I'm able to get an access token, but I'm not able to enter it so the build hangs until cancelled.

How should I setup authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Add the oath credentials to an EBS attached volume and copy them into place when the Agent is started.

1. [Configure bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+elastic+instances+to+use+the+EBS) for EBS attached volumes
2. [SSH into](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Accessing+an+elastic+instance) the instance, su to bamboo user
3. [Download](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) the Appengine SDK
4. [Run appcfg](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#appcfg_command) to be prompted for authentication

   1. appcfg -s my-app.appspot.com version
   2. follow instructions for oauth which will create /home/bamboo/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java
5. mkdir /mnt/bamboo-ebs/appengine
6. cp /home/bamboo/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java /mnt/bamboo-ebs/appengine
7. edit /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bin/customize-extras.sh (see [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Configuring+elastic+instances+to+use+the+EBS#ConfiguringelasticinstancestousetheEBS-EBSdirectoriesfilesImportantEBSdirectoriesandfiles)) adding the following

   1. cp /mnt/bamboo-ebs/appengine/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java /home/bamboo/
   2. chown bamboo:bamboo /home/bamboo/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java
8. Take a snapshot of the volume and assign the snapshot to your bamboo instance configuration

The next time bamboo starts a new instance the customize-extras.sh will be run and the necessary credentials will be in place for mvn appengine:update to find.